# How to use macros in printf function

Tags: c, macros

So I have this macro and a bunch others defined in my header file

```
#define COL1WIDTH 16
```

Which I want to use to print something like this:

```
word  25 Dir1/FileB 129 Sat Jan 1 00:00:02 2011 12 1(x4), 2(x2), 3(x2), 4(x2), 5(x2)
```

How does the syntax to get the macro work? Tried a bunch and it keeps screwing up.

Tried this

```
printf("%COL1WIDTHs\t",index->terms[0].term);
```

Comment: printf("%COL1WIDTHs\t",index->terms[0].term);

Comment: You can't just use the `*` width specifier?

Comment: Its part of the assesment. We have to use the macros specified.

Comment: No one is telling you to not use the macros.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Macros aren't expanded inside strings.  Here there's a decent workaround — write

```
printf("%*s\t", COL1WIDTH, index -> terms[0].term);
```

and `COL1WIDTH` will be used in place of the `*`.

Answer (score 9):

`printf("%" #COL1WIDTH "s\t", ...`

Read up on [token pasting and stringizing](http://kunaliiita.wordpress.com/2007/09/01/what-is-the-token-pasting-operator-and-stringizing-operator-in-c/) in the C pre-processor.

Answer (score 0):

**Modify your code as below and it will serve the purpose**

```
#define COL1WIDTH "16"    //define the constant in double quotes

printf("%"COL1WIDTH"s\t",index->terms[0].term); //place macro out of quotes so it can expand            
                                                //during the precompilation
```